# using jquery to group elements

Tags: jquery

I've got a whole bunch of elements that I need to group, but because it's being spat out of some machinery which I can't alter, I need to do so using jquery (which I'm fairly familiar with the basics of)

Basically I've got a load of p tags and divs loose inside a form element (yes bad markup, but that's another story). I need to group the p tags with the following one or two divs inside a fieldset.

I've tried inserting fieldset close and then start tag before each p element, but I guess the machinery that sorts it out wants to insert legal elements, so that doesn't work

Comment: it isnt particularly clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and clear it up. I've got something like this:

p
div
div
p
div
div
p
div
p
div

What I need to do it group each p element with the following one or two divs inside a fieldset element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a document where the markup looks something like this:

```
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<div>par1 div1</div>
<div>par1 div2</div>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<div>par2 div1</div>
<div>par2 div2</div>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<div>par3 div1</div>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<div>par4 div1</div>
```

And you want to end up with something like this:

```
<fieldset>
 <p>paragraph1</p>
 <div>par1 div1</div>
 <div>par1 div2</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
 <p>paragraph2</p>
 <div>par2 div1</div>
 <div>par2 div1></div>
</fieldset>
.....
```

If this is the case, then this jQuery snippet will do the trick:

```
$(function(){   
    $('p').each(function(index,item){
      var nextDiv = $(item).next();
      var followingDiv = $(nextDiv).next('div');
      $(item).wrap("<fieldset id='fieldset" + index + "'></fieldset>");
      $("#fieldset"+index).append(nextDiv).append(followingDiv);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd come up with something similar, although not as succinct as yours.

Answer (score 2):

@JoseBasillo's answer can be simplified and generalized a bit:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.children('p').each(function(index,item) {
    var $following = $(item).nextUntil('p, fieldset');
    $wrapper.append($('<fieldset>').append(item, $following));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5NXJ/)

The code converts

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
        ... (whatever but p or fieldset)
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
        ... (whatever but p or fieldset)
    ... (p followed by whatever but p or fieldset)
</div>
```

into

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <fieldset>
        ... (whatever but p or fieldset)
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        ... (whatever but p or fieldset)
    </fieldset>
    ... (fieldset containg [p followed by whatever but p or fieldset])
</div>
```

---

If someone prefers shorter code than readability, there's no need to use the variable `$following`:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.children('p').each(function(index,item) {
    $wrapper.append($('<fieldset>').append( item, $(item).nextUntil('p, fieldset') ));
});
```